# pass data from one class to another

Tags: python, oop, gtk3

I know this is asked several times here, and believe me, I have read many of them before posting my problem here. But I am yet to solve my problem. So, any help will be appreciated.

To start with, this involves 4 function in 4 different class (in separate file, accessed using `import`, and that is not a point of concern).

Here is the scriptlet from the functions involved:

**The MAIN program**

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        MenuElem = menu.MenuManager()
        TreeView = view.treeview()

        grid.attach(TreeView.view, 30, 0, 25, 21) #defined properly, 
                                                  #just not shown for bravity
```

**The MenuManager module(obviously in menu.py)**

```
import pybib
import view
class MenuManager(Gtk.UIManager):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parsing = pybib.parser()
        self.TreeView = view.treeview()

    def file_open_clicked(self, widget):
            filename = dialog.get_filename()
            self.parsing.parsing_read(filename)

            ####### HERE I NEED TO CALL VIEW.PY
            ## AND ATTACH IT TO THE GRID.ATTACH LINE
            ## iN MAIN.PY######
            ##e.g. self.Treeview()
```

The pybib.parser is rather small code, and also this is supposed to take arguments as input and output, so allow me to post in full:

```
class parser():
    # def __init__(self):
        def parsing_read(self, filename):
            import bibtexparser
            from bibtexparser.bparser import BibTexParser
            # from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
            from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import BibDatabase
            db = BibDatabase()
            with open(filename) as bibtex_file:
                parser = BibTexParser()
                db = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file, parser=parser)
                for i in range(0, len(db.entries)):
                    tuples = (i+1, db.entries[i].get("title"),
                              db.entries[i].get("author"),
                              db.entries[i].get("journal"),
                              db.entries[i].get("year"))
                    print(tuples)
                    #booklist.append(tuples) I should be able to pass the 
                    #booklist to view somehow
```

Now, finally, the **view.py**

```
class treeview():
    def __init__(self):
        #booklist = [] should take the booklist created by pybib
        self.bookstore = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, str, str, str)
        for ref in booklist:
            self.bookstore.append(list(ref))
        self.current_filter_language = None
        self.view = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.bookstore)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["Index", "Title", "Author",
                                          "Publishers", "Year"]):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            renderer.set_property("wrap-width", 400)
            if i > 2:
                renderer.set_property("wrap-width", 150)
            renderer.set_property("wrap-mode", 0)
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.view.append_column(column)
        print("view working")
```

I have checked the individual codes are working fine, but cant pass datas properly. I have kept the scriptlet as small as possible to my understanding.

I should mention that my experience in python is limited to scripting, in single file and this is the first time I am actually doing a `oop`.

Kindly help.

Comment: maybe you need `some_class.set_data( other_class.get_data() )`?

Comment: I am wondering if this is a common situation in oop, or artifact of my poor design?

Comment: Could you make it a bit clearer what you are trying to achieve? You say you need to call `view.py`, but you are already doing that, by importing it.